# finding the supremum and infimum of a complicated set

Tags: real-analysis

LEt $A = \{ (-1)^n \big( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \big) : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $. MY guess is that $\sup A = 1 $ and $\inf A = 0 $, but I don't know how to show this. How can I formally see this is true? thanks

Comment: Do you mean $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ or just $\sup$ and $\inf$?

Comment: You can see that $-2\in A$, so $\inf A = 0$ is not true.

Comment: I mean just sup and inf $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it as:
$$
f(n)=(-1)^n\left(1+\tfrac 1n\right)=\begin{cases}
1+\tfrac 1n&n\in 2\mathbb N\\
-\left(1+\tfrac 1n\right)&n\in 2\mathbb N+1
\end{cases}
$$
and so $A=\{f(2k)\}\cup\{f(2k+1)\}$ where $k\in\mathbb N$. For the first set we have
$$
\{f(2k)\}=\{1+\tfrac1{2k}\}=1+\left\{\tfrac 12,\tfrac 14,\tfrac 16,...\right\}
$$
and for the latter set we have
$$
\{f(2k+1)\}=\left\{-\left(1+\tfrac1{2k+1}\right)\right\}=-1-\left\{1,\tfrac 13,\tfrac15,...\right\}
$$
Then, if it is just $\sup A=1+\tfrac12$ and $\inf A=-1-1=-2$ it is quite simple.

---

Just for the record, we have $\limsup f(n)=1$ and $\liminf f(n)=-1$, since both $\tfrac12,\tfrac14,\tfrac16,...$ and $1,\tfrac13,\tfrac15,...$ converge to zero.

Comment: How can limit superior be defined for a set? I'd switch that $A$ for $f$.

Comment: @Regret: Of course you are right! (+1) for that comment.

Comment: Actually, upon looking into it, Wikipedia has a [definition of limit superior and inferior for sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Definition_for_a_set). According to this definition, I think your earlier claims that $\limsup A = -\liminf A = 1$ are correct. But perhaps it is still simpler for $f$.

Comment: @Regret: Yes, it seems simpler for $f(n)$ and there is no need to go into limit points of sets at this point. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$B = \{ (1+1/2n) : n\in \mathbb{N} \}$$

And
$$C = \{ -(1+1/(2n-1)) : n\in \mathbb{N} \}$$

Then $A = B \cup C $ and $B \cap C = \emptyset $

Every element of $C$ is -ve and every element of $B$ is +ve so $\inf(A) = \inf(C)$ and $\sup(A)=\sup(B)$.

The elements of $B$ form a monotonic decreasing sequence, so $\sup(B) = 3/2$, hence $\sup(A) = 3/2$. Similarly, $\inf(A)=\inf(C)=-2$.

Comment: Would the people who down voted my answer please leave me some feedback so that I might know what I did wrong??